# State-based analogue to distributive case

Tags: conlang-creation, grammar, morphology, case

I am developing conlang that has grammatical cases system for nominals that for each spatial case there is state-based case.

In Finnic languages grammatical cases that denote states occur, examples in Finnish:

- **Essive** (ESS) with the ending *-na*/*-nä* denotes being in state, corresponds to the combination 'as X' in English. *lapsi* - 'child', *lapsena* - 'as child / being a child'
- dialectal **Exessive** (EXESS) with the ending *-nta*/*-ntä* denotes a departure from state, corresponding to English 'from being X...'. *lapsi* - 'child', *lapsenta* - 'from being child'
- **Translative** (TRANSL) with the ending *-ksi* denotes a transition into state, corresponds to English 'to (becoming) X'. *aikuinen* - 'adult', *aikuiseksi* - 'to adult'. *lapsenta aikuiseksi* = '[maturing] from child to adult'.

There is clear spatial analogy:

- Locative ↔ Essive
- Ablative ↔ Exessive
- Allative ↔ Translative

You can construct state-based analogues to other spatial cases. For example, for the Prolative case ('through X') we can make Essive-Prolative, which would mean 'passing through a state of being X / through way of being X"

There is a Hungarian grammatical case called **Distributive** (DISTR) with the ending *-nként*, which is equivalent to 'per X'. For example, *hét* - 'week', *hetenként* - 'weekly, once per week'. It has a clear spatial-temporal nature.

I am trying to come up with a state based analogue for this case. Let's call it '*Essive-distributive*', but I am stuck with the expansion of the analogy. What exactly can 'per being in state' mean? Can anyone suggest a meaning and usage for such a case?

Comment: “each time you are asleep”, “each time Misha is on duty” could be examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting concept for a case. In my interpretation this kind of an abstract distributive case would apply in sentences like this one (a probably very clumsy reformulation of a famous first sentence in literature)

*Every unhappy family is different **in their unhappiness***.

I looked up the really case-rich conlang [Ithkuil](http://www.ithkuil.net/04_case.html) and did not find a precedent for this kind of case. Feel free to name it by any name you like. When you don't have an own idea, I suggest *respective case* for that one.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you could just make up a name. That's certainly a legitimate glossopoetical strategy.

In English, i'd just call it a distributive sense of the state-noun and have done with it: *Such-and-such only happens thrice per childhood, you know!*

Or ...*thrice childhoodly* if you prefer!

I frankly don't get the difference between LOC/ABL/ALL & ESS/EXESS/TRANSL, which I'm guessing must be a Finnish Thing.

I would understand "in the child" and "in childhood" to be locative senses of the thing-noun and state-noun respectively; "from the child" & "from childhood" likewise are ablative. So it is for "per child" and "per childhood", being the distributive sense.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly (big *if* there!), you are looking for a periodical state that repeats, not necessarily at the same time interval (though the two might in reality be linked) — as it happens we are using the sun rising as a proxy for the time passing.

This could be a tree blossoming, or losing its leaves. It could be the tide coming in. It could be birds migrating and passing through. It could be a woman's menstrual cycle. It could be being asleep/awake.